# `git pull` fails with "Not possible to fast-forward" for existing history

Tags: git

I've read a lot of other questions about the subject error message ("Not possible to fast-forward") but none of them seem to apply to my situation.  I create a branch (`git checkout -b issue-215`), make a change, and commit locally.  I push the change, then make new changes and another local commit:

```
* 4b797d2a - (HEAD -> issue-215) 
* 180a7ab5 - (origin/issue-215)
* 863ef01a - (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

ETA: as requested in a comment, the output of `git branch --all -v`:

```
* issue-215                 4b797d2a [ahead 1] 
  ... other branches ...
  master                    863ef01a 
  
  remotes/origin/issue-215  180a7ab5 
  ...other remotes....
  remotes/origin/HEAD       -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master     863ef01a
```

There are no new remote changes, but VSCode wants to pull before it pushes.  That's where I get this error.  So, to troubleshoot, I run `git pull origin issue-215` manually, and get the following output:

```
$ git pull origin issue-215
From ssh://my.repo/project
 * branch              issue-215  -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

Keep in mind, there are no new changes on the server, and the history from my current local commit back to the branch on the remote, back to `master` and `origin/master`, is a straight line.  I am not trying to merge or rebase, my local code is already a direct child of the branch I'm supposed to be pulling.

This only started happening about a month ago.  Previously, clicking the "sync" button in VSCode would work, but since then it always fails with this error message.  Could I have made some kind of gitconfig change that causes this behavior?  There's not much in my global gitconfig file, and it happens with at least 2 projects so I don't think it's something I did to the repository.

Comment: Please post the output of the command `git branch --all -v`.

Comment: Done. I trimmed other branch info, let me know if what I shared above is missing something important.

Comment: How are you pushing? Maybe the branch has set a different upstream. Does `git push origin issue-215:issue-215` work?

Comment: @knittl there is no problem with push. The specific issue I'm trying to solve is that a pull, that should print "Already up to date" and do nothing, is failing.  The answer below suggests that this may be a known issue with a specific version of git.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is a known issue with Git version 2.33.1.  It should be fixed in 2.33.2.**  Other generally-useful advice follows:

---

The "not possible to fast-forward" message means that you configured your `git pull` to use `git merge --ff-only`, perhaps using `git config pull.ff only`.  So `git pull` is dutifully running:

```
git fetch origin issue-215
git merge --ff-only FETCH_HEAD
```

and the second command gives you the error and stops.  (Edit: if you do this yourself manually and it *works*, you've run into the bug in footnote 1.)

> Keep in mind, there are no new changes on the server, and the history from my current local commit back to the branch on the remote, back to master and origin/master, is a straight line.

Clearly (from the error), it *isn't*.<sup>1</sup>  After the fetch, run:

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline FETCH_HEAD
```

to see *where* it's not; *why* it's not is a different question.  I suspect that the answer is something along the lines of:

- `origin` is GitHub;
- someone else is using the <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> or <kbd>SQUASH AND MERGE</kbd> buttons;
- and thus the commit(s) you obtain with `fetch` are *logically* equivalent to the commit(s) you pushed earlier, but have *different hash IDs*.

A regular merge or a rebase would then work, but `ff-only` won't.  (This is not the only possible explanation: e.g., other hosting sites have the same kind of effect, but sometimes with different button labels.)

> This only started happening about a month ago. Previously, clicking the "sync" button in VSCode would work, but since then it always fails with this error message. Could I have made some kind of gitconfig change that causes this behavior?

It could be something you changed, such as setting `pull.ff` to `only`.  It could be something *someone else* changed, such as switching from <kbd>MERGE</kbd> on GitHub to <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's a bug in Git 2.33.1 where `pull.ff only` rejects a no-op case that it should not have.  If you have Git 2.33.1, either upgrade it, or use `git fetch` and then `git merge --ff-only` for this case.

Comment: Do you have any more details about your footnote?  I think that must be it.  I'm running `2.33.1.windows.1`, which I probably updated a month or so ago.  Your `merge --ff-only` command shows "Already up to date" and your `log` command shows a straight line.  The repo is on a private Bitbucket and no one else is working on this project.

Comment: Ah: that's exactly the condition where Git spat out that error. There's nothing to do, so it can't do an actual fast-forward, so it complains instead of just saying "oh, I see, nothing to do". I haven't seen it myself but I tend to run a few releases behind on all my real systems, plus I never run `git pull`: I have an alias `git mff` = `merge --ff-only` and I run `git fetch`, then `git log`, then `git mff` most of the time.

Comment: The fix should be in the next release, which is coming pretty soon. Not sure how much delay there is for the `.windows` variant but probably no more than a day, so probably fixed by next week.

Comment: @torek yes, pretty much how I run things. I _never_ use pull, always `fetch`, followed by `merge` (even with the same `mff` alias \o/). I think the biggest problem is the linguistic proximity of push and pull. IMHO `pull` should only be offered to advanced users. fetch+merge clearly shows what is happening before the merge, pull simply shows errors that are of little value to new users.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I wasn't even actually trying to run `git pull` initially, this is just how VSCode's Git integration works. I normally find the little "sync" button to be handy, but it refuses to `push` if `pull` returns an error status.